# Plotly Pandas ta.alma behaves strange

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

As I started just over a week before and never looked at python I'm surprised how easy things can be done because of the good libraries available.

I'm converting a Tradingview script I've made to python and came to the point that I want to draw my indicator(s) and compare the results.

Drawing the alma indicator on a HA-chart it was un unpleasant surprise that the results are much different from TV.

I checked internet and found several resources and compared the codes I found.

```
# Pandas implementation of ta.alma provides VERY different results compared to TV !!
# Tradingview                => https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/arnaud-legoux-average/
# Github bug described       => https://github.com/twopirllc/pandas-ta/pull/374
# Github fix aug 15th, 2021  => https://github.com/twopirllc/pandas-ta/pull/374/commits/752b69e86e19db64cdf161981d0ad8c897efefea
# Original implementation    => https://www.sierrachart.com/SupportBoard.php?PostID=231318#P231318
# Prorealcode implementation => https://www.prorealcode.com/prorealtime-indicators/alma-arnaud-legoux-moving-average/
# What is wrong ?
```

First I notice that the calculation of Pandas.ta.alma works on all data while the TV and ProRealPro codes work on a a subset and ONE value for 'close'.

This raises the question "will I have to calculate ALL the data if I add just one new bar to the data?"

If so that seems inefficient and timeconsuming. How can I avoid that?

But much more important is 'what about the results from ta.alma?".
What causes the big difference? Am I using an old ta-lib as it was stated (and verified) that the bug had been fixed at aug 15th 2021?
How can I check that?

From the pictures attached you can see how the blue alma-line follows the candles very well at TV.

But with Pandas ta.alma and "offeset=0" it looks like the alma-line has been shifted.
I tried using 'offset=-9' and 'offset=-10' as I use 'length= 9' but the result is still far from TV.
Only if I use 'offset= -5' results are almost the same like TV.
Why should I use that value???

I also tried with and without df.fillna(0) but it doesn't make much difference (appart from the (undersirable line at the start).

Something must be wrong but what.
Like its is I can't use it despite all the positive things.
Any help will be appreciated.

My code demonstrates the problem if you change 'barsOffset = -5'

```
from ib_insync import *
from datetime import datetime

import pandas_ta as ta                      # TA-lib        https://youtu.be/lij39o0_L2I and https://youtu.be/W_kKPp9LEFY
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)     # Display all rows
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 25)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)        # equivalent with pd.options.display.width = 1000
pd.options.display.width = 0                # Panda will autodetect the size of the terminal window (and display columns accordingly)
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 50        # Maximum width of a column (rest will be replaced by ...)

ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=0)

duration = "1 D"            # How far back in history should data be retrieved
barSize = "1 min"           # Timeframe of the bars

contract = Index(symbol="EOE", exchange="FTA", currency="EUR")
ib.qualifyContracts(contract)
ticker = contract.symbol

bars = ib.reqHistoricalData(contract,        # the contract of interest
                        endDateTime= '',         # retrieve bars up until current time 
                        keepUpToDate=True,       # keep updating the data requires endDateTime= "")
                        formatDate= 1,           # formatDate=2 => for intraday => UTC
                        durationStr= duration,   # time span of all bars ('1 D')
                        barSizeSetting= barSize, # time period of 1 bar ('1 min')
                        whatToShow= 'trades',    # source of the data ('trades' => actual trades)
                        useRTH= True)            # show only data from Regular Trading Hours

df = util.df(bars)                  # Create a Pandas dataframe from the bars

distAlma = .85                      # Default distribution factor
sigmaAlma = 6                       # Default sigma
barsAlma = 9                        # Use 9 bars for calculating alma
barsOffset = -5                     # Not present in TV; It turns out it must be 5 or 6 to provide results comparable with TV

dfHA = df.ta.ha()                   # Fastest calculation of Heikin Ashi
df = pd.concat([df, dfHA], axis=1)  # Add columns generated by ta.ha to df
df["alma"] = dfHA.ta.alma(close="HA_close", length=barsAlma, sigma= sigmaAlma, offset_distribution= distAlma, offset=barsOffset)
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)          # Replace all NaN with 0 to avoid problems while comparing values but causes drawing lines for the first bars

strategy = 1                        # Discriminates between the type of candles to show combined with the strategy to use

if strategy == 1:
    openPrices = df.HA_open
    highPrices = df.HA_high
    lowPrices = df.HA_low
    closePrices = df.HA_close
    typeCandles = "HA-candles"
else:
    openPrices = df.open
    highPrices = df.high
    lowPrices = df.low
    closePrices = df.close
    typeCandles = "Price"

datePrices = df["date"]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(name= typeCandles, x= datePrices,
    open= openPrices, high= highPrices, low= lowPrices, close= closePrices))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=datePrices, y=df.alma, mode='lines', name='alma', line_color="rgb(0,0,255)", fill=None))

maxRange = df.HA_high.max()                   # Maximum price 
minRange = df.HA_low[df.HA_low>0].min()       # Minimum price skipping NaN and zero values
extraRange = 0.05 * (maxRange - minRange)     # Take 5% extra space for the range above and below

layoutFigures = dict ({
                    'title': ticker + " HA Candles",
                    'xaxis_title': "Date",
                    'yaxis_title': "Price",
                    'template': "plotly_dark",                                      # Dark backgroud
                    'dragmode': "pan",                                              # Start in "pan" mode
                    'yaxis_range': [minRange - extraRange, maxRange + extraRange],  # Set range yaxis from 5 % below lowest to 5% aboven highest price 
                    'xaxis_rangeslider_visible': False                              # Hide the zoom slider window
                     })
fig.update_layout(layoutFigures)                # Apply all layout specifications
fig.update_yaxes(fixedrange=False)              # Allow changing the yaxes

configFigures = dict({                          # https://plotly.com/python/configuration-options/#enabling-scroll-zoom
                'scrollZoom': True,             # Use the mousewheel for zooming
                'displayModeBar': True,         # Show the modeBar while hovering over it (False = invisible)
                'displaylogo': False,           # Hide plotly logo from modeBar
                'staticPlot': False,            # Make a dynamic plot (do NOT create a static plot)
                'toImageButtonOptions':
                {   'format': 'jpeg',           # one of png, svg, jpeg, webp  --> jpeg chosen
                    'filename': ticker + "_" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"),   # The name of the ticker will be used as filename
                    'height': 500, 'width': 700, 'scale': 1     # Multiply title/legend/axis/canvas sizes by this factor     
                },
                'modeBarButtonsToRemove': ['lasso2D', 'select2D']
                })
fig.show(config= configFigures)

ib.disconnect()
```

[image: Tradingview output of alma]

[image: ta.alma output with offset= 0]
[image: ta.alma output with offset= -9]
[image: ta.alma output with offset= -5]

Answer (score 0):

I found several references for coding alma and I implemented those for comparison.

```
 Pandas implementation of ta.alma provides VERY different results compared to TV !!
# Tradingview                => https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/arnaud-legoux-average/
#                               and https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000594683-arnaud-legoux-moving-average/#:~:text=To%20calculate%20the%20Arnaud%20Legoux,a%20width%20determined%20by%20sigma.
#                               and https://www.tradingview.com/script/rqxaTb6E-ALMA-Function-FN-Arnaud-Legoux-Moving-Average/
# Github bug described       => https://github.com/twopirllc/pandas-ta/pull/374
# Github fix aug 15th, 2021  => https://github.com/twopirllc/pandas-ta/pull/374/commits/752b69e86e19db64cdf161981d0ad8c897efefea
# Original implementation    => https://www.sierrachart.com/SupportBoard.php?PostID=231318#P231318
# Prorealcode implementation => https://www.prorealcode.com/prorealtime-indicators/alma-arnaud-legoux-moving-average/
# What is wrong ?
```

I also made my own implementation and optimized that code for speed. It turned out the implementation I've made using TV-code, ProRealCode and mine (non-optimized and optimized) give the EXACT same results up to seven digits. Both codes from Pandas provide different results.

The code I used for calling ta.alma is nothing more than

```
def AlmaTA(self, df, data= "HA_close"): 

    startTime = time.time()
    for test in range(0, self.counter):
        alma = df.ta.alma(close= data, length= 9, sigma= 6, offset_distribution= 0.85)

    dif = time.time() - startTime
    print("AlmaTA   ", dif)
    return alma
```

This code gives results that do not fit to the datapoints provided (see post above). Using the parameter 'offset' while calling ta.alma will not solve the problem. In fact I think it is principally wrong . The indicator as such does not have a parameter 'offset'. So Pandas mixes calculation results with input for plotting. In fact this introduces lagging if offset < 0 and causes that the last datapoints do not have an alma-value with them. What is the use of a zero-lag indicator like alma if you introduce lagging by using that offset parameter?

My code (and my implementation of the codes of TV and ProRealCode) fit well with the data provided looks like what I see on TV.[image]

My implemenation of the ProRealCode is

```
def AlmaReal(self, df, data= "HA_close", recalc= False):
# Prorealcode implementation => https://www.prorealcode.com/prorealtime-indicators/alma-arnaud-legoux-moving-average/
    startTime = time.time()
    for test in range(0, self.counter):
        prices = df[data]

        m = self.sensitivity * (self.bars - 1)
        s = self.bars / self.sigma

        size = len(prices)                      # Number of prices
        alma = [None] * size                    # Create the array (actually a list as Python has no arrays)
        for pos in range(self.bars-1, size):    # With 9 bars alma[8] can be calculated well
            WtdSum = 0
            CumWt  = 0
            for k in range(0, self.bars):
                Wtd = math.exp(-((k-m)*(k-m))/(2*s*s))
                WtdSum = WtdSum + Wtd * prices[pos - (self.bars - 1 - k)]
                CumWt = CumWt + Wtd
            alma[pos] = WtdSum / CumWt

    dif = time.time() - startTime
    print("AlmaReal   ", dif)
    return alma
```

My implementation for the TV-code looks similar. Of course I had to add a loop for calculating all rows of a dataset, something that is handled very different by TV.

I've put all implementations in a class and made it possible to call them for calculation of a single alma value (by recalc= False) or calculating the whole dataset (by recalc= True). I use recalc=True after reading historical data and recalc= False after retrieving data for a new bar.

My optimized (and fastest) code is

```
   def alma(self, df, data= "HA_close", recalc= False):
#        startTime = time.time()
#        recalc = True                               # For compatibiliy recalc can be set to false
    for test in range(0, self.counter):
        prices = df[data]
        maxIndex = self.bars - 1                # The maximum index of weight
        size = len(prices)                      # Number of prices
        calc = [None] * size                    # Create the array (actually a list as Python has no arrays)

        if size >= self.bars:                   # Normal situation            
            barStart = maxIndex if recalc else (size - 1) # Calculate just one bar or only the maxIndex bar
            for pos in range(barStart, size):   # Loop stops BEFORE size (because of the range-object used)
                sumAll = 0
                x = pos - maxIndex              # Index of the bar the price is taken into account
                for bar in range(0, self.bars): # What remains inside the loop can be easily calculated in parallel
                    sumAll += prices[x] * self.weight[bar]   # Time consuming exp-call removed from the loop
                    x += 1
                calc[pos] = sumAll              # As weights have been normalized at initialization
#                    print("alma[", pos, "]= ", alma[pos])
        # Handle the bars BEFORE self.bars => COULD be skipped if desired for compatibility reasons
        if (size == 1):                         # First bar 
            calc = prices[0]                    # Best possible result for alma[0] is the price itself
        elif recalc or (size < self.bars):      # Use smaller number of bars for alma until self.bars is possible
            calc[0] = prices[0]                 # Best possible result for alma[0] is the price itself
            for pos in range(1, self.bars-1):   # Calculate alma based on the numbers of bars present
                m = self.sensitivity * (pos - 1) 
                s = min(1, self.sigma / pos)    # Avoids s being larger than the number of bars
                x = -m * s
                sumAll = 0
                sumWeight = 0                   # Weight must be recalculated if the number of bars changed
                for bar in range(0, pos+1):
                    weight = math.exp(-0.5 * x * x)
                    sumWeight += weight
                    sumAll += prices[bar] * weight
                    x = x + s
                calc[pos] = sumAll / sumWeight
#                    print("alma[", pos, "]= ", alma[pos])
#                                 
#        dif = time.time() - startTime
#        print("Alma   ", dif)
    return calc
```

This uses data calculated once at initialization of an instance.

All codes I've seen do not calculate an alma value for the first few bars as not enough bars are vailable yet. If you look at the results of each alma calculation you'll see that the calculated value is quite near the value of the most current bar (of course: alma aims to be a zero lag indicator). To me it makes sense to calculate the 'best possible' value and use that for drawing the first points. That's why I added that feature to my code.

```
class MyAlma():

    # https://capital.com/arnaud-legoux-moving-average#:~:text=ALMA%20is%20a%20technical%20analysis,points%20within%20the%20specified%20period.
def __init__(self, df, bars= 9, sigma= 6, sensitivity= 0.85):                     
    self.bars = bars                        # Number of bars taken into account
    self.sigma = sigma                      # Standard deviation of the Gaussian filter (lower --> more false signals)
    self.sensitivity = sensitivity          # Smoothness of the Gaussian filter (between 0 [noisy] and 1 [lagging])
    self.weight = None                      # How much each bar counts in the calculation

    self.setParameters(bars= self.bars, sigma= self.sigma, sensitivity= self.sensitivity)

    self.counter = 1 #50                      # Just for testing speed different methods
#        df_Alma = self.AlmaTest(df)
#        df_Alma.to_excel("T:/dfAlma.xlsx")

def getParameters(self):
    return [self.bars, self.sigma, self.sensitivity]

def setParameters(self, bars= 9, sigma= 6, sensitivity= 0.85):
    error = (int(bars + 0.00001) < 1) | (sigma < 1) | (sigma > bars) | (sensitivity < 0) | (sensitivity > 1)
    if error == False:
        self.bars = int(bars + 0.00001)         # Floating point protection
        self.sigma = sigma
        self.sensitivity = sensitivity

        # Calculate the weights of each bar
        m = self.sensitivity * (self.bars - 1)
        s = self.sigma / self.bars              # Avoids dividing later
        s = s * math.sqrt(0.5)                  # Math   a * b * b = (sqrt(a) * b) * (sqrt(a) * b)
        x = -m * s                              # Addition instead of multiplication later
        factor = 0
        self.weight = [None] * self.bars        # Idea: calculate this once and store it in the instance
        if self.bars == 1:
            self.weight[0] = 1
        else:
            for bar in range(0, self.bars):     # Calculates 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 if self.bars == 9
                y = math.exp(-x*x)              # Use a local variable instead of referring weight[bar] two times
                factor += y                     # Total sum of all weights
                self.weight[bar] = y            # Weight for this bar
                x = x + s                       # No need for a multiplication here
            factor = 1 / factor                 # Avoid several divides while normalizing
            for bar in range(0, self.bars):
                self.weight[bar] *= factor      # Normalizing weights avoiding multiplication while calculating alma 
    return error
```